# Django QuerySet filter method returns multiple entries for one record

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Trying to retrieve blogs (see model description below) that contain entries satisfying some criteria:

```
Blog.objects.filter(entries__title__contains='entry')
```

The results is:

```
[<Blog: blog1>, <Blog: blog1>]
```

The same blog object is retrieved twice because of JOIN performed to filter objects on related model. What is the right syntax for filtering only unique objects?

Data model:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, related_name='entries')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Sample data:

```
    b1 = Blog.objects.create(name='blog1')
    e1 = Entry.objects.create(title='entry 1', blog=b1)
    e1 = Entry.objects.create(title='entry 2', blog=b1)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use distinct()

i.e.:
`Blog.objects.filter(entries__title__contains='entry').distinct()`

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

Comment: Thanks. I just didn't expected such behavior from the magical ORM :) The doc actually mentions this situation but I expected it to be described in section about querying related objects.

Comment: Could you add a link to the respective parts of the docs for reference?

Answer (score 5):

Use the [distinct](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) method

```
Blog.objects.filter(entries__title__contains='entry').distinct()
```

Comment: +1 Thanks. Josh was the first who answered, accepting his answer.