# Django: How to get related objects of a queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Assume I have two models:

```
A:
    pass

B:
    a = foreign_key(A)
```

Now, I have a query set

```
bs = B.objects.filter(...)
```

I want to get all the `a` of `bs`, which means every `a` which is referenced by `b` for which `b` is in `bs`.

Is there a way to do so? I think in sql, a simple join will do, I don't know if django support this.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use `__in`:

```py
A.objects.filter(b__in=bs)
```

or you can avoid creating the bs queryset at all, and follow the relation directly in your query:

```py
A.objects.filter(b__<bcondition>=<bvalue>)
```

For example, if the filter used to create `bs` was:

```py
bs = B.objects.filter(name="Banana")
```

Then you could filter the `A` objects using:

```py
A.objects.filter(b__name="Banana")
```

Bear in mind that there are a number of different ways you can filter, and that the filter functionality is quite extensive, so it is worth reviewing the [filter documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)

Comment: Could you please extend on the second method? I don't understand what is `bcondition` and `bvalue` in this context.

Comment: It's whatever expression OP used to get `bs` in the first place.

Comment: I didn't remember that we could just use the related model directly as a field in the filter query. +1

Answer (score 1):

Extending Daniel's solution, using `__in` might return duplicate records if using a related model.

For example:

`A.objects.filter(b__in=bs).count()` could be more than `A.objects.all().count()`

For me, using `distinct()` worked as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2654309/1526703) SO answer

`A.objects.filter(b__in=bs).distinct()`